# Is it natural to say "don't step on that empty carton box as you might get your leg caught/trapped in it"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

Your child is standing on an empty carton box.

Because the box is not strong enough to support the child's body so his leg might get in the box.

Is it natural to say "**don't step on that empty carton box as you might get your leg caught/trapped in it**"?

I think "**caught**" or "**trapped**" are way too much for a carton box.

In other situation, "**caught**" or "**trapped**" are suitable, for example,  “**I accidentally got my leg stuck/caught/trapped in the drain grate.**”

[image]

Comment: The cardboard in your picture can be called a carton or a box, not a 'carton box'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think either would work, especially if you're trying to add a bit of hyperbole to stop a child accidentally doing something silly.

To an adult, I'd likely use **caught** because to me that feels more temporary. But you could also consider just being more direct:

> You might fall into the box.

> Your leg might break the lid.

Or to use a more colloquial phrase:

> The lid might **give way**.